# Difficult dataframe lookup query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty sure there is a question for this already so if someone could just point me in the right direction.

I have two dataframes, DF1:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| Survived |  Surname  | FamilySize | NumSurvived | FamilySurvivalRate |
+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
|        0 | Braund    |          2 |           0 | 0                  |
|        1 | Cumings   |          1 |           1 | 1                  |
|        1 | Heikkinen |          1 |           1 | 1                  |
|        1 | Futrelle  |          2 |           1 | 0.5                |
|        0 | Allen     |          2 |           1 | 0.5                |
|        0 | Moran     |          3 |           1 | 0.333333333        |
|        0 | McCarthy  |          1 |           0 | 0                  |
|        0 | Palsson   |          4 |           0 | 0                  |
+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

and DF2:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| Survived |  Surname  | FamilySize | NumSurvived | FamilySurvivalRate |
+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
|        0 | Braund    |          2 |           0 |                    |
|        1 | Cumings   |          1 |           1 |                    |
|        1 | Heikkinen |          1 |           1 |                    |
|        1 | Futrelle  |          2 |           1 |                    |
|        0 | Allen     |          2 |           1 |                    |
|        0 | Moran     |          3 |           1 |                    |
|        0 | McCarthy  |          1 |           0 |                    |
|        0 | Palsson   |          4 |           0 |                    |
+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

For each surname in DF2 I need to find the FamilySurvivalRate for that surname in DF1 and put the value in DF2. If the surname is not in DF1 it needs to be 0.

Thanks!

Comment: Are both `DataFrame` with same size?

Comment: @jezrael - No, and there are duplicate Surnames but the same FamilySurvivalRate counts for each duplicate surname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created from `df1` and [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace non matched values:

```
print (df2)
  Survived    Surname  FamilySize  NumSurvived
0         0     Braund           2            0
1         1   Cumings1           1            1 <- change surname for no match
2         1  Heikkinen           1            1
3         1   Futrelle           2            1
4         0      Allen           2            1
5         0      Moran           3            1
6         0   McCarthy           1            0
7         0    Palsson           4            0

s = df1.set_index('Surname')['FamilySurvivalRate']
df2['FamilySurvivalRate'] = df2['Surname'].map(s).fillna(0)
print (df2)
   Survived    Surname  FamilySize  NumSurvived  FamilySurvivalRate
0         0     Braund           2            0            0.000000
1         1   Cumings1           1            1            0.000000
2         1  Heikkinen           1            1            1.000000
3         1   Futrelle           2            1            0.500000
4         0      Allen           2            1            0.500000
5         0      Moran           3            1            0.333333
6         0   McCarthy           1            0            0.000000
7         0    Palsson           4            0            0.000000
```

Comment: @ZackJoubert - it depends what need - if need first value - `s = df1.drop_duplicates('Surname').set_index('Surname')['FamilySurvivalRate']` of if need `mean` - `s = df1.groupby('Surname')['FamilySurvivalRate'].mean()`

Comment: @ZackJoubert not exactly, because need remove duplicate by `Surname` and it is index of Series. So first remove duplicates by column and then creae index by set_index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge both dataframes based on the entries present in DF2, then to fill missing values with 0:

```
(
    df2
    # Remove FamilySurvivalRate from DF2, as it is of not interest
    .drop(columns=["FamilySurvivalRate"]
    # Retrieve possibly existing values from df1
    .merge(df1, how="left")
    # Fill missing values with 0
    .fillna({"FamilySurvivalRate": 0})
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
DF2.loc[DF2['Surname']==DF1['Surname'],['FamilySurvivalRate']] = DF1['FamilySurvivalRate']
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will solve your problem

```
df2 = df2.drop('FamilySurvivalRate', axis=1)
df2 = pd.merge(left=df2, right=df1[['Surname','FamilySurvivalRate']], on='Surname')
df2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the same could be achived using merge().

```
df2.merge(df1[["Surname","FamilySurvivalRate"]],how ='left', on = "Surname").fillna(0)
```